# Write the predicate count(Name, Count) to count the number of occurrences given name in family member lists

Tags: prolog

i did task 2 and 3 but i can't do task 1. Сan you help me with it.
In the Prolog program, facts are given for the relation family_info(Family,
Members) about family members (Family — name of family, Members — list of names of family members).

1. Write the predicate count(Name, Count) to count the number of occurrences
   given name in family member lists.
   the first task must be performed using a dynamic Prolog database without involving list generation prediсates and the aggregate library;

```
family_info(family1, [name1, name2, name3]).
family_info(family2, [name4, name5]).
family_info(family3, [name1, name2]).
family_info(family4, [name6, name7, name8]).
family_info(family5, [name1]).
family_info(family6, [name9, name10]).
family_info(family7, [name5, name6, name7]).
family_info(family8, [name1, name2, name3, name4]).
family_info(family9, [name4, name5, name6]).
family_info(family10, [name5, name6, name7, name8]).
```

Answer (score 0):

Can count the old-fashioned way:

```
reset_count :-
    retractall(count(_)),
    assert(count(0)).
    
inc_count :-
    count(N),
    N1 is N + 1,
    retract(count(N)),
    assert(count(N1)).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- reset_count.
?- inc_count.
?- inc_count.

?- count(N).
N = 2.
```

Comment: This is not exactly what is expected of me, the name should be entered, but the number of times it occurs should be output. As I understand your code doesn't work like that